# (Android) Develop a Calendar with tasks

Tags: android

I want to create my own Calendar, in a app Android.
I have determinate this layout :

I need at least 10 reputation to post image so i upload my picture on a website. You can [view it here](http://s30.postimg.org/vql17dpxd/layout_Calendar.jpg):

[image: Phone screenshot]

Item1, Item1, Item1 will be day, month and year. 
I do not know at all how to develop the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Swipe tab layout which is very much popular and easy to create.

Android developer has created separate library for using this.

`TabLayout tabLayout = ...;
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));` \

I think you should go through this [Android Developer Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) to get more idea.

have a look and reply.

Comment: I don't really understand. Swipe tab is just for switch to another layout, right ?
My question is maybe not clear. I need advise for the code. I find this : https://github.com/square/android-times-square. it seem good. In the perfect case, i juste need a solution already developp

Comment: what do you want??
do you want that android times square library to use in your app??
you can simple add by compile the library in your app

compile 'com.squareup:android-times-square:1.5.0@aar'